# MySQL query with one variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'main_table' with 3 columns :
'player', 'points' and 'drop_date'

I have 1 variable ($date) with different values:

```
$date == '2012-06-01'  
$date == '2012-05-01'  
$date == '2012-04-01'
```

I Have 1 MySQL query:

```
$query = "
  select *
  from main_table
  where `drop_date` > '$date'
    AND `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  LIMIT 1
";
```

GOAL :
I would like to run ONE query with different passes (1pass per value)

I have tried :

```
<?php
$date['date'] = '2012-06-01';  
$date['date'] = '2012-05-01'; 
$date['date'] = '2012-04-01';

foreach($date as $title => $actual_date) {
  query = "
    select *
    from main_table
    where `drop_date` > '$actual_date'
      AND `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('$actual_date', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    LIMIT 1
  ";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['Player'];
  echo $row['Points'];
}
```

Comment: Notice: you are overwriting the same slot in the array at `$date['date'] = `

Comment: Your code in the last example boggles my mind: You use the same key in your dictionary for each date, presumably these should be distinct; then, the bit that runs through the query results is in a separate scope to where said results are defined, which needless to say won't work... Don't get me started on parameterising your query!

Comment: you have overwritten your `$date['date']` with the last value, that is '2012-14-01'. The other values were lost.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD) (see the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/a4i0f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your while in the foreach loop.

```
<?php
$date[0] = '2012-06-01';  
$date[1] = '2012-05-01'; 
$date[2] = '2012-04-01';
foreach($date as $title => $actual_date)
{
    query = "select * from main_table where `drop_date` > '$actual_date' AND `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('$actual_date', INTERVAL 1 YEAR) LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['Player'];
        echo $row['Points'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You keep overwriting the same variable over and over... and then you run the query but only fetch results for the last one. How do you expect it to work?

Try this:

```
$date = Array("2012-06-01","2012-05-01","2012-04-02");
foreach($date as $actual_date) {
    if( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `main_table` where `drop_date`>'".$actual_date."' and `drop_date`<=date_add('".$actual_date."',interval 1 year) limit 1"))) {
        echo $result['Player'];
        echo $result['Points'];
    }
}
```

Note that I skipped putting the query in a variable, and putting the query result in a variable, and just one-lined the whole thing. Since you have `limit 1` the query will only return one row, so there is no need to `while`-loop it.

Comment: quick update : wanted to echo $actual_date as well in output but it kept showing 2005,2006,2007 instead of "2012-06-01","2012-05-01","2012-04-02", any idea?

Comment: it was calculating it actually, for instance 2012-06-01 = 2005 ! so it was displaying the result. added " to Thomas's answer to sort it out!

Answer (score 1):

Do not overwrite your values. Do this to keep all 3 values.

```
<?php 
$date['date'][] = '2012-06-01';  
$date['date'][] = '2012-05-01'; 
$date['date'][] = '2012-04-01';

print_r($date);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-06-01
            [1] => 2012-05-01
            [2] => 2012-04-01
        )

)
```

Then use

```
foreach ($date['date'] as $actual_date) {

 $query = "
   select *
   from main_table
   where `drop_date` > '$actual_date'
     AND `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('$actual_date', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
   LIMIT 1";

   echo $query."<br />";

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
select *
    from main_table
    where `drop_date` > '2012-06-01'
      AND `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('2012-06-01', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    LIMIT 1
  <br />
    select *
    from main_table
    where `drop_date` > '2012-05-01'
      AND `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('2012-05-01', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    LIMIT 1
  <br />
    select *
    from main_table
    where `drop_date` > '2012-04-01'
      AND `drop_date` <= DATE_ADD('2012-04-01', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    LIMIT 1
  <br />
```